# Jest setup with Vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm attempting to learn how to use Jest, and what better way than to do so with a personal project.

I got jest all installed, and configured (correctly, as far as I can tell). But my coverage report is all messed up. Can someone assist with this? Tests are running, mostly at least. But the issue here is with the coverage report. Below are relevant configs.

Facebook's docs leave a lot to be desired when it comes to config.

Package.json "jest" key

```
"jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(styl)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue",
      "jest-serializer-html"
    ],
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "src/**/*.vue",
      "!**/vendor/**",
      "!**/__mocks__/**",
      "!**/__tests__/**",
      "!test/e2e/**"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "**/node_modules/",
      "**/__tests__/*"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "**/node_modules/"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  }
```

Project layout

```
[ ] build
[ ] config
[ ] coverage
[ ] build
[ ] src
  [ ] assets
  [ ] components
    [ ] Module 1
      [ ] __tests__
         [ ] __snapshots__
         file module1.test.js
      file module1.vue
  [ ] config
  [ ] router
  [ ] store
  [ ] stylus
  file main.js
  file App.vue
```

Leaves my coverage report looking like: **(which i wish just showed me paths relative to my root, and the actual file name, not "unknown")**

```
    Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
    Tests:       1 failed, 16 passed, 17 total
    Snapshots:   2 passed, 2 total
    Time:        0.719s, estimated 1s
    Ran all test suites.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
    File                                                           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
    All files                                                      |    71.62 |    63.04 |    83.33 |    67.69 |                |
     root                                                          |    71.05 |       80 |      100 |    62.07 |                |
      unknown                                                      |    71.05 |       80 |      100 |    62.07 |... 151,152,154 |
     root/Users/absolute/path/to/project/src/components/Module1    |    72.22 |       50 |    83.33 |    72.22 |                |
      Module1.vue                                                  |    72.22 |       50 |    83.33 |    72.22 |... 151,152,154 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm seeing the same issue